# CSS3 polygons without images, how to?

Tags: html, css, polygon, css-shapes

I'm building a website, that goes something like this
[image: without expansion]

The two structures at the top ae static and the four at bottom are dynamic, when I say dynamic, I mean expandable, something like this

[image: with expansion]

Since these are just colors, shapes and shadows, I believe it's possible to use CSS3 to create them. But I'm having a hard time on doing so. I tried even using CSSHat, but the result is awful.

This is the example shape
[image: individual shape]

This is the generated code:

```
width: 1920px;
height: 341px;
-moz-border-radius: 0 1920px 1920px / 0 181px 56px;
-webkit-border-radius: 0 1920px 1920px / 0 181px 56px;
border-radius: 0 1920px 1920px / 0 181px 56px; /* border radius */
-moz-background-clip: padding;
-webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
background-clip: padding-box; /* prevents bg color from leaking outside the border */
background-color: #3b0f1d; /* layer fill content */
```

And the result looks like this:
[image: converted shape]
A live example can be found here http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/mgDwd

Which is the best way to achieve this goal?

Comment: In all seriousness, if you're trying to create arbitrary shapes in the browser, CSS is probably the wrong tool for the job. Have you considered using proper graphics? With SVG, for example, this would be very easy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Spudley, the problem is that I want my "divs" or "sections" or any other HTML elements to have those shapes, that's why I don't think I could achieve that with SVGs, am I wrong?

Comment: By expandable do you mean that you want them to interact with the mouse as in div:hover ?

Comment: It has to expand like in the image on click, but show some feedback on hover as well.

Answer (score 4):

You can use CSS `transforms` to rotate the divs.

I have made the bottom divs **dynamic**, and added some content to **yellow** and **green** div.

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.top, .top2, .yellow, .green, .bottom, .bottom2 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 140%;
    position: relative;
    left: -10%;
    transform-origin: 0% 100%;
    transition: 0.6s ease;
}
.top {
    top: -180px;
    background: #3C101D;
    transform: rotate(4deg);
}
.top2 {
    background: #931930;
    transform: rotate(-1.5deg);
}
.yellow {
    background: #F0810E;
    top: -200px;
    transform: rotate(0.6deg);
}
.content {
    display: block;
    width: 65%;
    position: relative;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
}
.yellow .content {
    transform: rotate(-0.6deg);
}
.green {
    background: #425949;
    top: -320px;
    transform: rotate(-1.4deg);
}
.green .content {
    transform: rotate(1.4deg);
}
.bottom {
    background: #501B2B;
    top: -480px;
    transform: rotate(1.4deg);
}
.bottom2 {
    background: #3C101D;
    top: -600px;
    transform: rotate(-0.6deg);
}
.yellow:hover, .green:hover, .bottom:hover, .bottom2:hover {
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="top2"></div>
<div class="yellow">
    <div class="content">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?</div>
</div>
<div class="green">
<div class="content">But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
<div class="bottom2"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [CSS transformations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) (*on `:before`/`:after` elements*) to simulate the effects..

Something like (*demo at http://codepen.io/gpetrioli/pen/LHbIE*)

```
<div class="background">
    <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```

and

```
background{background-color: #3c101d}
.shape{
  width: 800px;
  height: 341px;
  background: white;
  display: block;
  margin:10px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.shape:before{
  content:'';
  width:110%;
  height:30px;
  background:#3c101d;
  position:absolute;
  height:100px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  transform-origin:0 100%;
  transform: translateY(-100px) rotate(5deg);
}
.shape:after{
  content:'';
  width:110%;
  height:30px;
  background:#3c101d;
  position:absolute;
  height:100px;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  transform-origin:0 0;
  transform: translateY(100px) rotate(-2deg);
}
```

*notice: this code uses the standard CSS properties. Add the vendor prefixed ones where required*

Comment: Using Google Chrome 27 this example displayed me a rectangle

Comment: @JoãoPauloApolinárioPassos enable prefix-free from the CSS options (see http://codepen.io/seraphzz/pen/Aklfa) or add the vendor prefix for webkit for the transform (`-webkit-transform:`)..

Answer (score 1):

**Here's your solution for the "CSSHat shape":-**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
    .background{
        background-color: #3c101d;
        padding:22px 28px;
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .shape{
        height: 30px;
        border-left: 645px solid white;
        border-top: 80px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    }
</style>
<div class="background">
    <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The trick to getting all the shapes you desire above is to play with:- all border sizes, all border colors and **either** the Height or Width of the div.

Codepen:- http://codepen.io/mrmoje/pen/EaQNOP

Answer (score 1):

Those shapes look like perspective transforms to me. http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/perspective/ I don't believe there is a generator to go to the extremes of having the left and right be wider than a parent with overflow hidden for the orange section of the 2nd graphic.

You can see from this perspective generator while it is spinning that all angles are possible. http://desandro.github.io/3dtransforms/examples/perspective-03.html

**As an alternative markup instead of CSS3 which also does not require images**

I would suggest using SVG to markup all the polygons. It is much easier and supported by all CSS3 browsers.